# Последовательное заполнение гугл табилцы

Tags: telegram-bot, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Имеется гугл-скрипт, вебхуком связанный с телеграм ботом. Я хотел, чтобы код по одному типизированному форварду и двум последующим реплаям на него заполнял строку в гугл-таблице, но столкнулся с проблемой того, что скрипт реагирует на каждое сообщение в боте и обрабатывает их отдельно.

```
  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var text = contents.message.text
  var txtar = text.split(" ");
  var sheetName = "Тест";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
  sheet.getSheetByName(sheetName).appendRow([maintext[3], "-", maintext[2], maintext[1], "-", maintext[0]]);
```

Таким образом скрипт заполняет таблицу, но каждое обработанное сообщение он выводит на новую строчку. Могу ли я через ключ, например, дополнять уже заполненную строку(в качестве ключа можно использовать время форварда первого сообщения).
Если редакция уже затронутых строк возможна, то каким методом это осуществимо, в мануалах класса SpreadsheetApp нашел только метод `setCurrentCell(cell)`, но он не очень удобен в использовании.

Comment: Вы должны задать конкретный вопрос. На этот дать точный ответ невозможно.

Comment: @oshliaer, вопрос был в методе для класса или иного решения проблемы заполнения в несколько заходов. На него Вами дан был ответ, благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setCurrentCell` не только неудобен, но и невозможен, т.к. Таблица не имеет характеристики `Active` при исполнении такого скрипта.

В данном случае вам необходимо совершать записи построчно, преобразуя их позже, чтобы не заставлять Telegram ждать ответа.

Например,

```
| UID | KEY   | VALUE  |
|-----|-------|--------|
| 1   | step1 | Привет |
| 1   | step2 | Купить |
| 2   | step1 | Привет |
| 1   | step3 | Пока   |
| 3   | step1 | Привет |
```

И, уже исходя из этих данных, строить вытянутую вправо таблицу.